# Will the compactions be fewer if partial columns are updated?

Tags: cassandra, scylla

I have a table which has a lot of columns.

Does the database need fewer compactions if only partial columns are updated compared with that all columns are updated?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, each update is smaller, so memtables take more time to fill, and compaction happens less frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Compactions depend on the strategy you have defined.
In case of STCS and LCS lesser updates means less data and hence less compactions.
For TWCS, compactions depend on time window you have defined.